# C++ convert char array read from a binary file into an integer

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17

Following code is to read 4 bytes from a binary file, to store the value in an char array, then convert it to an integer. It works well, but I just wonder why or how the last code line can work, i.e. `result = (int)r_buff[3] + ((int)r_buff[2]<< 8) + ((int)r_buff[1]<<16) + ((int)r_buff[0]<<24);`.

2nd, What is the symbol `<<` doing here?

3rd, any better substitute codes of this?

Many thanks.

The source I saw was originally from http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/16887/.

```
int buf_size = 4;   
char r_buff[buf_size-1];
int result;

string b_file = "my_binary_file.bin";
ifstream reader;
reader.open(b_file , ios::in | ios::binary);
reader.read(r_buff, buf_size);

result = (int)r_buff[3] + ((int)r_buff[2]<< 8) + ((int)r_buff[1]<<16) + ((int)r_buff[0]<<24);
```

Comment: read about << here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: Learn about how bits, bitshift operators, and multi-byte Integer endian work. Also, your code has 2 bugs - allocating a 3-byte array to read a 4-byte value, and using a non-standard way to allocate that array. There is an easier way to read a 4-byte Integer without using a `char[]` array at all: `int32_t result; reader.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&result), 4);` And then you can swap the endian of the integer if needed, such as with `ntohl()` or equivalent function.